# Send text file attachment with an email

Tags: android, email, attachment

I am trying to attach a text file in order to send it with an email 
but whenever i open the Email app it says that the file does not exist Help Please

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"musabyahya1005@gmail.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(directory+"/data.txt"));

try {
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "An Error Happened ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: what kind of value does directory have?

Comment: Oh i missed to explain that in this app i am writing on a file by bufferdwriter   
directory=dir.getAbsolutePath(); has the absolute path for that file

Comment: Where is that directory located?

Comment: i tried to print the directory that what i got 
/storage/emulated/0/MyFile

Comment: Ok so can you confirm that /storage/emulated/0/MyFile/data.txt exists? Try my code posted below, this works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to send files with email, make sure that they are on a public accessible location and that you tell it that it is a file you want to send. Use this code as an example.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822").putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"fake@example.com"}).putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Mail subject").putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "lalalala");
String targetFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "tmp" + File.separator + "test.txt";
Uri attachmentUri = Uri.parse(targetFilePath);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + attachmentUri));
```

Comment: That worked out 
i am trying to do that for 2 months 
Thank you very much

Comment: Uri.fromFile(f) is better